# How do you simulate car arrivals having a normal distribution while setting the peak times in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am currently simulating a parking place in AnyLogic and wanted to set the arrival rate with a normal distribution. But I don't exactly know how to set a normal distribution peaking for example exactly at 3pm.
Any suggestions are appreaciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to change the arrival rate according to a normal distribution in time.

That means that you need some function (tableFunction might work for instance) that gets the current time as an input and the arrival rate as an output.

You will then change the arrival rate every hour, or every 10 minutes depending on your model... your arrivals will continue following a poisson arrival, but your arrival rate throughout the day will follow any distribution you want.

Comment: Thank you Felipe, I will check this out!